# Moving beyond writing simple functions within document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, document-ready

When building a site, as a personal preference, I like to create a main javascript file, that has window.load and window.ready right at the top of the file.

As a means of legibility I tend to refactor any logic I want within these functions, into their own functions, and typically I only run the functions if the elements exist within the DOM.

For the most part I feel like this is cleaner than dumping everything directly into the load/ready functions, but as my javascript skills increase and I start to write more anonymous functions, and my code is starting to look like a bit of a tangle as the document ready section starts to get longer.

For the purposes of this question I would like to know:

1. Is there a better way to only run a function/code that to check for length the way I do?
2. Is there a better way to incorporate the above check into the way I write my plugins?
3. **Primary Question:** How do I move beyond writing single jQuery centric scripts, as a means to better my javascript skills.

I've provided an example of what my files tend to look like.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if ( $('#el-1').length !== 0 ) { $('#el-1').addClass('add'); }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( $('#el-2').length !== 0 ) { new my_plugin('#el-2');  }
  if ( $('#el-3').length !== 0 ) { simple_function();  }
  /* This starts to get messy when there's multiple checks, 
  // longer function names, and different libraries etc.
  */
});

var simple_function = function() {
  //do the short thing
};

;(function( window, $ ) {
  'use strict';
  function my_plugin( el, options ) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.options = $.extend( this.defaults, options );
    this._init();
  }
  my_plugin.prototype = {
    defaults : {
      something: 'something'
    },
    _init : function() {
      // do the things
    }
    _internalFunction: function() {
      // do the things
    },
    externalFunction: function() {
      // do the things
    }
  }
  window.my_plugin = my_plugin;
})( window , jQuery );
```

Comment: Well, TBH this is probably an opinion based question. What's the best, I don't know. I have my preference, but it might not suit you. For instance, i like to use `require.js` to split my files and I created my own view framework that use `data-view` attribute to automatically init the view. Some may prefer to use router such as the one in Backbone...

Comment: I currently work for an agency building once off marketing sites with a quick turn around... I changed my question to better suit, I think my primary issue is:

"How do I move beyond writing single jQuery-centric scripts, as a means to better my javascript skills."

Keeping in mind I need it to be a fairly quick and lightweight process. I agree that my question is subjective.... I will research require.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is already technically correct. Everything else depends on the frameworks, technologies & loading methods etc. that you use. Otherwise it's all about opinion and convention. If you work for a company that sets down very strict code authoring rules then you have to stick to those anyway.

When it comes to splitting your code into multiple files you can use a module definition format/pattern like requirejs or commonjs to better manage your dependencies and modules.

If you are talking about best practices and design patterns for javascript and jquery then the following resources might help:

[JQuery Boilerplate:](https://jqueryboilerplate.com/) This website illustrates many examples and explains how and why they are considered best practices. (Helped me a lot)

[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns:](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) This is a free online book written by Addy Osmani a Google Engineer who is also one of the developers at jqueryboilerplate.com

Edit: The book on design patterns is especially helpful if you wish to better structure your code.

Comment: I read up on require js overnight and now I feel like this is definitely the read down which I should be heading.

In particular reading the following from requirejs website helped http://www.requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html 

Thanks so much for the design patterns book, this also looks like a good resource.